How can I receive big nested webhook in C# ASP.NET Web API? I am able to receive small data
I am able to receive small amounts of data, but I'm unable to receive a big chunk of data via webhook in my API. How could I receive big data in my API?
I am able to receive this data:
namespace interaktapi.Models
{
    public class MyJsonSample
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}

How can I receive this data?
namespace interaktapi.Models
{
    public class MessageData
    {
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
        public List<Message> message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string channel_phone_number { get; set; }
        public List<Traits> Traits { get; set; }
    }

    public class Traits 
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        public int total_orders_count { get; set; }

        public string last_order_id { get; set; }
        public string last_order_name { get; set; }
        public string total_spent { get; set; }
        public bool whatsapp_opted_in { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public string User_id { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class Message  
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string chat_message_type { get; set; }
        public string channel_failure_reason { get; set; }
        public string message_status { get; set; }
        public string received_at_utc { get; set; }

        public string delivered_at_utc { get; set; }
        public string seen_at_utc { get; set; }
        public string campaign_id { get; set; }

        public bool is_template_message { get; set; }

        public string raw_template { get; set; }

        public string channel_error_code { get; set; }
        public string message_content_type { get; set; }
        public string media_url { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public List<Metadata> metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metadata
    {
        public string source { get; set; }
        public SourceData source_data { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceData
    {
        public string callback_data { get; set; }
    }
}

Here's the code in which I am able to receive above data:

Please guide me in actionable steps how could I modify my code to receive the nested webhook?

So, you have an web api that is able to receive some (or much) data in the body. In a first step you have to ensure, that your server is correctly configured to allow bigger body sizes. For this take a look at this answer. When you're able to upload a corresponding body sample to your api, the next step would be to check, if the JSON matches your model.

What do you mean "unable"? Is there an exception? Is something null that shouldn't be? Does nothing happen? What does the client receive?
